# unable to show a result from join query in php

Tags: php

I have a join query for selecting a value from two tables. But it shows an error that says uncaught error
code:
[picture of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3v2Xm.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3v2Xm.jpg)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary** to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Dhungana You Write at the end of code where at last end

Comment: You should define your table name as" table as c, table2 as s. Where c.id = s.id and c.id =?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define your table name as" table as c, table2 as s. Where  c.id = s.id and c.id =?